# Repeat task with threading and Tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code, the Thread calls function name file_add once, but I want to repeat the function every minute, for example, but because I use the Tkinter library (user interface), so when closing the application it causes a problem and stops working.

```
class TimerApp:
    # in conctuctor
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(1.0, self.file_add)
       
    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.start()


    def stop_timer(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
    
    # function for exmaple
    def file_add(self):
        print("file add function repeat")

timerapp = TimerApp()

# when start app call this funtion
def startApp():
    timerapp.start_timer()

# when click logout button call this function
def logoutApp():
    tiemrapp.stop_timer()
```

Comment: You mention tkinter but there is nothing to show how tkinter relates to your code.

Comment: What problem occurs when you close the app?

Comment: I have something working but not sure if this does what you want. I'll post it now.

Comment: I don't think threading works with tkinter any more, you might want to try tkthread (https://pypi.org/project/tkthread/) instead

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Output is sent to a `Label` with two `Buttons` for control.

A slight change to prevent `timerApp` access before it is run with `start_flag`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading

start_flag = True

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry( "300x60" )

label = tk.Label( master, text = "Message banner" )
label.pack(fill = "both", expand = True )


class TimerApp:

    # in constuctor
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(1.0, self.file_add)
       
    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def stop_timer(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
    
    # function for exmaple
    def file_add(self):
        label["text"]= "file add function repeat"



# when start app call this function
def startApp():
    global timerapp, start_flag

    start_flag = True

    timerapp = TimerApp()
    label["text"] = "timer Started"
    timerapp.start_timer()

# when click logout button call this function
def logoutApp():
    if start_flag:
        timerapp.stop_timer()
        label["text"] = "timer Stopped"
    else:
        label["text"] = "TimerApp not running"

tk.Button(
    master,
    text = "StartApp",
    command = startApp).pack(
        side = "left", fill = "both", expand = True )

tk.Button(
    master,
    text = "logoutApp",
    command = logoutApp).pack(
        side = "right", fill = "both", expand = True )

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the timer when the GUI is closed using `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onClose)` to register a callback to the onClose function

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk

class TimerApp:
    # in conctuctor
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(5.0, self.file_add)
       
    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.start()


    def stop_timer(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
    
    # function for exmaple
    def file_add(self):
        print("file add function repeat")

timerapp = TimerApp()

# when start app call this funtion
def startApp():
    timerapp.start_timer()

# when click logout button call this function
def logoutApp():
    timerapp.stop_timer()

def onClose():
    timerapp.stop_timer()
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=startApp).grid()
tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=logoutApp).grid()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onClose)
root.mainloop()
```